# WebPart Zones to be always right aligned to the browser

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Is there a way to make the web part zones always right aligned to the browser? Current they are shown left aligned? I'm hoping for a solution without using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way (or hack) would be use a different page layout such that you have you have two web parts (left and right).  On the left webpart, you can put a simple content editor and have a table of specific width % (or assign the width % in webpart properties) such that the right webpart is right-aligned to the browser.

Not sure if there is a way in Sharepoint Designer to set the alignment relative to the browser.